# Android studio 3.0 error with sweet-alert-dialog library

Tags: android

On click to show the dialog this error occurs

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation-name:
>   cn.pedant.SweetAlert.Rotate3dAnimation error:null

Anybody have solution step by step?

Comment: Read https://github.com/pedant/sweet-alert-dialog/issues/160

Comment: github.com/pedant/sweet-alert-dialog/issues/160. It doesn't have the clear solution.

Comment: Probably bug. `Downgrade` version.

Comment: That's a good idea. But I think another person have another way to solve the problem by coding. I need the way step by step!

Comment: Use module structure.

Comment: Yes ! I found solution here "i solved this error by modify the source code
the mothod createAnimationFromXml from Class OptAnimationLoader
add } else if (name.equals("YOURPATH.Rotate3dAnimation")) {
anim = new Rotate3dAnimation(c, attrs);
}" I want to do by this way, can you show me step by step

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use this library is the same just with new features 
https://jitpack.io/p/Leogiroux/sweet-alert-dialog

Comment: Okey, Thanks. I'll Do that

Comment: Error man! "Failed to resolve: com.github.Leogiroux:sweet-alert-dialog:"

Comment: How to solve the "Failed to resolve" problem, please?

Comment: use this com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.1

Comment: Although in the download section says to use "com.github.Leogiroux:sweet-alert-dialog:" it lacks of version number so use the other compiler that is "compile 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.1' as @evilshok stated

Answer (score 18):

Add this library to `app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.1'
}
```

**Usage:**

```
SweetAlertDialog pDialog = new SweetAlertDialog(this, SweetAlertDialog.PROGRESS_TYPE);
pDialog.getProgressHelper().setBarColor(Color.parseColor("#A5DC86"));
pDialog.setTitleText("Loading");
pDialog.setCancelable(false);
pDialog.show();
```

for more usages about progress read [THIS](https://jitpack.io/p/Leogiroux/sweet-alert-dialog).

Answer (score 5):

Add this library to `app/build.gradle`:

`dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.1'
}`

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

I got the solution!

if you are using `implementation 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'` library, just add the below line in your `proguard-rules.pro` file.

`-keep class cn.pedant.** { *; }`

Answer (score 2):

Add this to proguard-rules.pro

```
-keep class cn.pedant.SweetAlert.Rotate3dAnimation {
    public <init>(...);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

BTW, for those still following this thread:

This is happening because it's failing to turn the `50%` string from `pivotX` / `pivotY` into the integer '50', which it needs.

It's failing on this line in `OptAnimationLoader.java`, specifically the call to `.newInstance(c, attrs);`

```
anim = (Animation) Class.forName(name).getConstructor(Context.class, AttributeSet.class).newInstance(c, attrs);
```

I forked the repo and changed `50%` to `50` and it worked.  This is the error I was seeing:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: cn.pedant.SweetAlert.Rotate3dAnimation error:null
    at cn.pedant.SweetAlert.OptAnimationLoader.createAnimationFromXml(OptAnimationLoader.java:77)                      
    at cn.pedant.SweetAlert.OptAnimationLoader.createAnimationFromXml(OptAnimationLoader.java:64)
    at cn.pedant.SweetAlert.OptAnimationLoader.createAnimationFromXml(OptAnimationLoader.java:41)
    at cn.pedant.SweetAlert.OptAnimationLoader.loadAnimation(OptAnimationLoader.java:22)
```

For the record, this repo is unmaintained, and you should switch over to @thomper 's fork at https://github.com/pedant/sweet-alert-dialog/.

Comment: @TrịnhMinh would you be kind enough to tell us how?

Comment: I fixed this error a long time ago. I can't remember.

Answer (score 1):

Add the error_frame_in.xml animation file to the anim directory of res

[image]

Open the `error_frame_in.xml` file add the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha="1"
        android:duration="400"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by just changing

```
mErrorInAnim = OptAnimationLoader.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.error_frame_in);
```

to

```
mErrorInAnim =  (AnimationSet)OptAnimationLoader.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.error_x_in);
```

in the file SweetAlertDialog.java

happy coding..

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.1'` library, just add the below line in your `proguard-rules.pro` file in project section. It will work in the production version of your app. I tried and it worked perfectly.

```
-keep class cn.pedant.** { *; }
```